# Append HTML content in a TextView

Tags: java, android, html, textview, spannablestring

Lets imagine a use case that I need to create a logger on Android that displays everything in a TextView.

So I create a multi-line TextView. Then initially have a method for adding simple text to the TextView:

```
TextView output; // Initialized in onCreate
public static void log(final String text) { // Method is called always when Log.log is called
    output.append(text + "\n");
}
```

That works like a charm but I want to add red colored text (or text background) when the log returns some bad information (e.g. HTTP 500). So I've updated the method and used some html:

```
public static void log(final String text) {
  String newText = output.getText().toString();
  if (text.contains("500")) {
    newText += "<font color='#FF0000'><b>" + text + "</b></font><br />";
  } else {
    newText += text + "<br />";
  }
  output.setText(Html.fromHtml(newText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

But it always formats just the current 'text' and everything before that (output.getText()) weren't formatted. Seems that TextView doesn't preserve the text with HTML tags and just decorated at once.

I tried something like:

```
spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(color), 0,
                    text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

output.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Which did the colored background but just of current text. I would like to have output like white lines and when some 500 then show some red lines (so it's dynamic).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some more deeper searching I found SpannableStringBuilder and I changed the code:

```
public static void log(final String text) {
  // Could be instantiate just once e.g. in onCreate and here just appending
  SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(output.getText());
  if (text.contains("500")) {
    ssb.append(coloredText(text + "\n", Color.parseColor("red")));
  } else {
    ssb.append(text).append("\n");
  }
  output.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}


private static SpannableString coloredText(String text, int color) {
  final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
  try {
    spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(color), 0,
                    text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return spannableString;
}
```

And that did the trick